# Parse JSONArray present in generic ArrayList

Tags: java, json, arraylist, codenameone, org.json

I have some issue with JSONArray, As I am having a JSON data present in generic ArrayList but I don't have any idea that how to parse that json data and display in list, I am using org.json library

**Below is my json data which is present in array list:**

```
[{"story":"Gaurav Takte shared a link.","created_time":"2017-02-14T19:08:34+0000","id":"1323317604429735_1307213186040177"},{"story":"Gaurav Takte shared a link.","created_time":"2017-02-02T14:22:50+0000","id":"1323317604429735_1295671703860992"},{"message":"Hurray....... INDIA WON KABBADI WORLD CUP 2016","created_time":"2016-10-22T15:55:04+0000","id":"1323317604429735_1182204335207730"},{"story":"Gaurav Takte updated his profile picture.","created_time":"2016-10-21T05:35:21+0000","id":"1323317604429735_1180682575359906"},{"message":"Friends like all of you \u2026 I would love to keep forever.\n#oldmemories with # besties \n#happydays","story":"Gaurav Takte with Avi Bhalerao and 5 others.","created_time":"2016-10-21T05:33:55+0000","id":"1323317604429735_1180682248693272"},{"message":"\"सर्वांना गणेशचतुर्थीच्या हार्दीक शुभेच्छा.\nतुमच्या मनातील सर्व मनोकामना पूर्ण होवोत , सर्वांना\nसुख, समृध्दी, ऎश्वर्य,शांती,आरोग्य लाभो हीच\nबाप्पाच्या चरणी प्रार्थना. \"\nगणपती बाप्पा मोरया , मंगलमुर्ती मोरया !!!","story":"Gaurav Takte with Avi Bhalerao and 18 others.","created_time":"2016-09-05T05:06:58+0000","id":"1323317604429735_1133207030107461"}]
```

**And here is my code:**

```
ArrayList data_arr1= (ArrayList) ((Map) parsed.get("posts")).get("data"); JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data_arr1); for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){ try { JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i); Log.p(obj.toString()); } catch (JSONException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); } }
```

So how can i parse this json using org.json library.

Comment: Have you tried using a search engine? I get the feeling that there are 10 question like this each day here ...

Comment: And hint: read about **raw** generic types. You are using them; but you should better not.

Comment: @GRV_Droid Do not post code in a comment. Edit the question to clarify. Delete the comment.

Comment: I tested your json response example it's work fine.. See my Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best solution of in-proper json response.
You can try this code I hope it works good..

```
            String result = "Your JsonArray Data Like [{}]";

            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String story = null;
                    try {
                        story = jsonobject.getString("story");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String msg = null;
                    try {
                        msg = jsonobject.getString("message");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String ct = jsonobject.getString("created_time");
                    String id = jsonobject.getString("id");

                    if (msg == null){
                        msg = "";
                    }
                    if (story == null){
                        story = "";
                    }
                    arrayList.add(story + msg + ct + id);
      //            Smodel is getter model
      //            arrayList.add(new Smodel(story, msg, ct, id));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: can you explain what result field contain? means json response or my arraylist which contain json

Comment: result  is String value of response Jsonarray

Comment: Welcome.  accept my answer and close this que. @GRV_Droid